# Show only time from datetime.MinValue without converting to string in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, mvvm

I want to convert datetime to time without using tostring since my chart is bound to date on axis.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
date = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute, date.Second, date.Kind);
```

What now very much confused after reading solutions all different??

Thankyou.

Comment: Your question is also very confusing. A `DateTime` always has a date and a time portion, you cannot "remove" anything from it. You can do that only if you display it as string.

Comment: I have a date that is getting data for my financial chart, but i have to show only time. not the date of the data

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? They may not be the same because your first `date` can have milliseconds part your second `date` has `0` as a miiliseconds.

Comment: Maybe you want a `TimeSpan`: `date.TimeOfDay`

Comment: thats not working even i tried that too.

Answer (score 2):

```
var timeOfDay = date.TimeOfDay;
var hour = timeOfDay.Hours;
var minute = timeOfDay.Minutes;
```

Comment: i have to put the time from datetime to another datetime. not like all separate.

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh you can pass these values in the constructor of the new DateTime object

Comment: constructor has its default date only time i can change this way.